# Issue with setDataSource in CakePHP 2.4.8

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I wrote a behavior, [Cascadable](https://github.com/houseoftech/CascadableBehavior), that merges records across 2 databases. It works sort of like CSS, where the more local style overrides the global. The behavior uses `$this->setDataSource()` to switch between the databases. This was working up until the 2.4.8 release when this [commit was made to the Model.php file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/d526fda).

Here's sort of an extraction from the behavior:

```
$Model->setDataSource( 'alt' );
$altData = $Model->find($findType, array(
     'contain' => false,
     'conditions' => array(
          $Model->alias.'.id' => $ids
     ),
     'callbacks' => 'before'
));
```

If the callbacks option is set to false, I get Missing Database Table errors about tables that are only present in the default (parent) datasource.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but after 2.4.8 upgrade it always uses the wrong (parent) database instead of the child. I can revert Model.php back to the 2.4.7 version to fix the issue. I realize this is difficult to replicate because it only breaks in my very specific database structure.

### MySQL Table Schema example:

#### Parent Database Table

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `price` float(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `active` (`active`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0;

INSERT INTO `parent_db`.`products` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, 'Big Box of Goodies', '99.99', '0');
```

#### Child Database Table

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `active` (`active`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0;

INSERT INTO `child_db`.`products` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, 'Small Box of Surprises', NULL, '1');
```

### Query Results

#### From Parent DB

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'id' => '1149',
            'name' => 'Big Box of Goodies',
            'price' => '99.99',
            'active' => false
        )
    )
)
```

#### From Child DB with *working* Cascadable behavior (child record is merged into parent record, ignoring null values)

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'id' => '1149',
            'name' => 'Small Box of Surprises',
            'price' => '99.99',
            'active' => true
        )
    )
)
```

### Workaround:

Setting the schemaName manually after using setDataSource fixes the issue for me.

```
$Model->setDataSource( 'alt' );
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
$dataSources = ConnectionManager::enumConnectionObjects();
$Model->schemaName = $dataSources['alt']['database'];
```

Comment: Have you tested that reverting this change actually fixes your problem? I can't test it right now, but having a look at the actual database source implementations, it looks like this change could indeed break things. An easy workaround would be to set the schema name manually afterwards, however I would still report it as a bug, respectively comment in [**the pull request**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/3210), just to make sure whether this is now the intended behavior.

Comment: Yes, reverting to 2.4.7 fixes the issue, even reverting just the Model.php file fixes it. I [commented on the pull request](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/3210#issuecomment-43437992). Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have raised an issue for this: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/3720, as of 2.5.1 the functionality is still broken.